# Is it possible to override request payload in python?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I've been looking for this answer for quite long but still with no results. I'm working with selenium and I need to override one request which is generated after the submit button has been clicked. It contains data in json format under "Request payload" in chrome dev tools. I found something like seleniumwires which provides some functionality like request.overrides but I'm not sure it is working as I want. Can anyone give me some hint where to start or which tools are approporiate to do that ?